# mat-card-content overflows angular material card

Tags: angular-material

Using angular material 8.2.0

I have created a dashboard template from the [angular material schematics](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#dashboard-schematic). This creates a number of mat-grid-tile within a mat-grid-list. In each tile there is a mat-card

Now I am trying to fit put a google map and some charts.js into the content section of the cards that are generated.

Since for both the map and the charts I need to specify the height of the container div, I was hoping that simply using `height:100%` would do it. However when using `height:100%` on `mat-card-content` it overflows the parent mat-card.

A simple example demonstrating this is:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ucak6j

Any hints into the issue or a potential workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `height: 100%` on an element inside a block element, it uses the parent element's height. But this parent element is the `mat-card` which also contains the `mat-card-header` so you need to leave room for that. The easiest way to fix that is to use a flexbox layout on the `mat-card`:

```
.dashboard-card-content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.dashboard-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```